# Registry error while trying to install Oracle 11g on Win 2008 R2

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, oracle-sql-developer

I am new to Oracle and trying to install Oracle database 11g Enterprise Edition on Windows 2008 Server R2 but getting this error all the time...

It gives me error when updating registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/software/oracle/OracleMTSRecoveryServiceProtid_0`..

It says `The specified home name was not found in the registry`

Could anyone please help me out to resolve this..

Comment: Do you have any other errors in the installation log?

Comment: i aborted the installation... no other error

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](https://community.oracle.com/message/9584421):

An old ORACLE_HOME had not been deinstalled/removed correctly and the following registry information still existed:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Protid_0]  
"Name"="HTTP"  
"Host"="hostname"  
"Port"="49155"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Setup]  
"NumberOfInstalls"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Setup\All Versions]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Setup\All Versions\1]  
"Version"="11.2.0.1.0"  
"Home"="SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_OraDb11g_home2"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Setup\Current Version]  
"Version"="11.2.0.1.0"  
"Home"="SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_OraDb11g_home2"
```

Please do the following,

1. Verify that:
   the above registry keys exist in the Windows registry, and
   they point to an old %ORACLE_HOME% which no longer exists on the server
   If the registry keys do not exist or if they point to a valid %ORACLE_HOME% on the server, there is another cause for the error which needs to be investigated further. Do not perform step 2.
2. After verifying both of the above points, remove the above registry keys and perform the 11.2 installation again. The error should no longer occur.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the path in attached registry file as per your installation dirs of Oracle and import it.

below content save with file name as OracleDBConsoleorcl.reg

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\SYSMAN\OracleDBConsoleorcl]
"EMDROOT"="D:\\Oracle\\product\\11.2.0\\dbhome_1"
"ORACLE_HOME"="D:\\Oracle\\product\\11.2.0\\dbhome_1"
"EMSTATE"="D:\\Oracle\\product\\11.2.0\\dbhome_1\\localhost_orcl"
"CONSOLE_CFG"="dbconsole"
"ORACLE_SID"="orcl"
"ORACLE_HOSTNAME"="localhost"
"TIMEOUT"="15"
"TRACE_LEVEL"="16"
```